# vim supertab, toward a best way to insert a tab

Tags: vim, tab-completion, supertab

I really like the supertab plugin. Reaching <C-x><C-p> is a bit too long and mapping it to tab  gives me a better workflow. However, sometime I just want to insert a regular tab and for this I need to insert a space first, i.e. foo<Space><Tab>bar.

This pollute my sources with useless spaces before each tab char (this assuming I don't use expandtab).

I am wondering is there is a smarter way to use auto-completion ?

1. Going back to <C-x><C-p> which is much slower
2. Using another key mapping like
3. Using supertab with a wiser feature: 
   i.   Automatically insert a <Tab> if I press a char that doesn't match any of the possible completions. 
   ii.  Inserting a real tab with
4. ???

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: It is more common to start completion via `<c-p>` not `<c-x><c-p>`. SuperTab defaults to using `<c-p>` as well. `<c-x><c-p>` is completion for just the current file which is different from standard `<c-p>` which uses a few more sources (See `:h 'completeopt'). In my opinion it is best to rip off the SuperTab bandaid and learn to love `<c-p>` and friends

Comment: I love your idea Peter. Unfortunately, I have a big issue with this. Because our world is not perfect a lot of people prefer using other *bad* editors. When I have to use them because I do not have any other choice, I feel lost and all my attempts getting polymorphic reflexes were unsuccessful. Thus, I'm trying to bring vim's behaviour a bit closer to the evil "standard".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress the Supertab trigger and insert a literal tab by pressing `<C-v><Tab>`. (On Windows, that frequently is `<C-q><Tab>`.)

Supertab also provides a mapping for direct input, by default `<C-Tab>`; see `:help supertab-mappingtabliteral`. That default key combination probably only works in GVIM, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just another try.

You can have a global substitute after editing work like:

```
:%s/ \t /\t/g
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. Can be useful in my "reformat" script which removes trailling spaces and do some other things